# How can I drag and drop in javascript over an iframe background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

This issue is **only in Chrome**, it works fine in FF/IE/Edge.
I am trying to make a drag and drop builder that will allow users to add a video background to the page. Everything is OK except when setting a video background elements can no longer be dropped.

I tried placing a transparent div over the iframe, disabling pointer events, can't get it to work at all.

I created a codepen ( https://codepen.io/talextech/pen/aPGmmJ ) showing the issue in action. Try dragging the red square inside the white/dashed rectangle above. If you remove the youtube embed it works fine.

Is there any way to get the drag and drop working with the youtube video in the background in Chrome?

```
<div id="dragto"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="dragme" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
<iframe id="videobg" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FQ6_Fr-Fd5k" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? The codepen sadly shows an error for me

Comment: No, still couldn't find a solution or any hack to get around this :( Only temporarily disabling the video while dragging.